# Cant get Overloaded operators to work

Tags: c++

I have to writ a class file statistician. In this, i have to overload the ==, !=, +, and * operators, but i cannot seem to get them to work and i dont know what i am doing wrong. The + operator is supposed to return all numbers from s1 and s2. the == determines if s1 == s2, and the * multiplies the numbers of s by the scale. Here is my header file:

```
// FILE: statistician.h
//
// CLASS PROVIDED: statistician
//      (a class to keep track of statistics on a sequence of real numbers)
//      This class is part of the main_statistics.
//
// CONSTRUCTOR for the statistician class:
//       statistician();
//       Postcondition: The object has been initialized, and is ready to accept
//       a series of numbers. 
//
// PUBLIC MODIFICATION member functions for the statistician class:
//      void next(double nextNum)
//          Postcondition: nextNum has been given to the statistician as the next number in
//          the series of numbers.
//      void reset();
//          Postcondition: Clears statistician, ready for use.
//
// PUBLIC CONSTANT member functions for the statistician class:
//      int length() const
//          Postcondition: The return value is the length of the series of numbers that has
//          been given to the statistician.
//      double sum() const
//          Postcondition: The return value is the sum of all the numbers in the series.
//      double mean() const
//          Precondition: length() > 0
//          Postcondition: The return value is the mean of all numbers in the series.
//      double getMin() const
//          Precondition: length( ) > 0
//          Postcondition: The return value is the smallest number in the series.
//      double getMax() const
//          Precondition: length( ) > 0
//          Postcondition: The return value is the largest number in the series.
//
// NON-MEMBER functions for the statistician class:
//      statistician operator +(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
//          Postcondition: The return value contains all the numbers of series s1 and series s2.
//      statistician operator *(double scale, const statistician& s)
//          Postcondition: The statistician that is returned contains the same
//          numbers of s multiplied by the scale.
//      bool operator ==(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
//          Postcondition: The return value is true if s1 and s2 have the same length, 
//          the same  mean, the same minimum, the same maximum, and the same sum.
//      bool operator !=(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
//          Postcondition: The return value is true if s1 and s2 are not identical
//
// VALUE SEMANTICS for the statistician class:
// Assignments and the copy constructor may be used with statistician objects.

#ifndef STATS_H     // Prevent duplicate definition
#define STATS_H
#include <iostream>

namespace main_stats
{
    class statistician
    {
    public:
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        statistician();

        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void next_number(double nextNum);
        void reset();

        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        int length() const;
        double sum() const;
        double mean() const;
        double minimum() const;
        double maximum() const;

        // FRIEND FUNCTIONS
        friend statistician operator +(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2);
        friend statistician operator *(double scale, const statistician& s);

    private:
        int count; // How many numbers in the sequence
        double total; // The sum of all the numbers in the sequence
        double smallest; // The smallest number in the sequence
        double largest; // The largest number in the sequence
    };

    // NON-MEMBER functions for the statistician class
    bool operator ==(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2);
    bool operator !=(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2);
}

#endif
```

here is my implementation file:

```
// FILE: statistician.cxx
// CLASS IMPLEMENTED: statistician (see statistician.h for documentation)

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "statistician.h"
#include <cassert>

namespace main_stats
{
    statistician::statistician()
    {
        reset();
    }

    void statistician::next_number(double nextNum)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            count = 1;
            total = nextNum;
            smallest = nextNum;
            largest = nextNum;
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            count += 1;
            total += nextNum;

            if (nextNum < smallest)
                smallest = nextNum;

            if (nextNum > largest)
                largest = nextNum;
        }

        mean();
    }

    void statistician::reset()
    {
        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        smallest = 0;
        largest = 0;
    }

    int statistician::length() const
    {
        return count;
    }

    double statistician::sum() const
    {
        return total;
    }

    double statistician::mean() const
    {
        assert(count > 0);
        return total / count;
    }

    double statistician::minimum() const
    {
        assert(count > 0);
        return smallest;
    }

    double statistician::maximum() const
    {
        assert(count > 0);
        return largest;
    }

    bool operator ==(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
    {
        return (s1 == s2);
    }

    bool operator !=(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
    {
        return !(s1 == s2);
    }

    statistician operator + (const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
    {
        statistician s3;
//      s3 = (s1.sum + s2.sum);

        return s3;
    }

    statistician operator * (double scale, const statistician& s)
    {
        double multiply;
        multiply = (s.total * scale);
        return s;
    }
}
```

And here is the file i am using to test:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>    // Provides memcpy function
#include "statistician.h"
using namespace main_stats;
using namespace std;

bool close(double a, double b)
{
    const double EPSILON = 1e-5;
    return (fabs(a - b) < EPSILON);
}

int test1()
{
    // Test program for basic statistician functions.
    // Returns 62 if everything goes okay; otherwise returns 0.

    statistician s, t;
    int i;
    double r = 0;

    if (s.length() || t.length()) return 0;
    if (s.sum() || t.sum()) return 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        s.next_number(i);
        r += i;
    };

    if (t.length() || t.sum()) return 0;
    if (s.length() != 10000) return 0;
    if (!close(s.sum(), r)) return 0;
    if (!close(s.mean(), r / 10000)) return 0;

    // Reset and then retest everything
    s.reset();
    t.reset();
    r = 0;

    if (s.length() || t.length()) return 0;
    if (s.sum() || t.sum()) return 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        s.next_number(i);
        r += i;
    };

    if (t.length() || t.sum()) return 0;
    if (s.length() != 10000) return 0;
    if (!close(s.sum(), r)) return 0;
    if (!close(s.mean(), r / 10000)) return 0;

    return 62;
}

int test2()
{
    // Test program for minimum/maximum statistician functions.
    // Returns 7 if everything goes okay; otherwise returns 0.

    statistician s, t, u;
    double r = 1000;
    char n[15] = "10000000000000";

    if (s.length() || t.length()) return 0;
    if (s.sum() || t.sum()) return 0;

    memcpy(&r, n, sizeof(double));
    r = 1 / r;
    s.next_number(r);
    if ((s.minimum() != r) || (s.maximum() != r)) return 0;
    r *= -1;
    t.next_number(r);
    if ((t.minimum() != r) || (t.maximum() != r)) return 0;

    u.next_number(100); u.next_number(-1); u.next_number(101); u.next_number(3);
    if ((u.minimum() != -1) || (u.maximum() != 101)) return 0;

    return 7;
}

int test3()
{
    // Test program for + operator of the statistician
    // Returns 7 if everything goes okay; otherwise returns 0.

    statistician s, t, u, v;

    if (s.length() || t.length()) return 0;
    if (s.sum() || t.sum()) return 0;

    t.next_number(5);
    u.next_number(0); u.next_number(10); u.next_number(10); u.next_number(20);

    v = s + s;
    if (v.length() || v.sum()) return 0;
    v = s + u;
    if (!(u == v)) return 0;
    v = t + s;
    if (!(t == v)) return 0;
    v = t + u;
    if (v.length() != 5) return 0;
    if (!close(v.sum(), 45)) return 0;
    if (v.minimum() != 0) return 0;
    if (v.maximum() != 20) return 0;
    if (!close(v.mean(), 45.0 / 5)) return 0;
    v = v + t;
    if (v.length() != 6) return 0;
    if (!close(v.sum(), 50)) return 0;
    if (v.minimum() != 0) return 0;
    if (v.maximum() != 20) return 0;
    if (!close(v.mean(), 50.0 / 6)) return 0;
    return 7;
}

int test4()
{
    // Test program for * operator of the statistician
    // Returns 7 if everything goes okay; otherwise returns 0.

    statistician s, t, u;

    if (s.length() || t.length()) return 0;
    if (s.sum() || t.sum()) return 0;

    u.next_number(0); u.next_number(10); u.next_number(10); u.next_number(20);

    s = 2 * u;
    if (s.length() != 4) return 0;
    if (!close(s.sum(), 80)) return 0;
    if (s.minimum() != 0) return 0;
    if (s.maximum() != 40) return 0;
    if (!close(s.mean(), 80.0 / 4)) return 0;

    s = -2 * u;
    if (s.length() != 4) return 0;
    if (!close(s.sum(), -80)) return 0;
    if (s.minimum() != -40) return 0;
    if (s.maximum() != 0) return 0;
    if (!close(s.mean(), -80.0 / 4)) return 0;

    s = 0 * u;
    if (s.length() != 4) return 0;
    if (!close(s.sum(), 0)) return 0;
    if (s.minimum() != 0) return 0;
    if (s.maximum() != 0) return 0;
    if (!close(s.mean(), 0)) return 0;

    s = 10 * t;
    if (s.length() != 0) return 0;
    if (s.sum() != 0) return 0;

    return 7;
}

int test5()
{
    // Test program for == operator of the statistician.
    // Returns 7 if everything goes okay; otherwise returns 0.

    statistician s, t, u, v, w, x;

    if (s.length() || t.length()) return 0;
    if (s.sum() || t.sum()) return 0;

    t.next_number(10);
    u.next_number(0); u.next_number(10); u.next_number(10); u.next_number(20);
    v.next_number(5); v.next_number(0); v.next_number(20); v.next_number(15);
    w.next_number(0);
    x.next_number(0); x.next_number(0);

    if (!(s == s)) return 0;
    if (s == t) return 0;
    if (t == s) return 0;
    if (u == t) return 0;
    if (!(u == v)) return 0;
    if (w == x) return 0;

    return 7;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    int result;

    cerr << "Running statistician tests:" << endl;

    cerr << "TEST 1:" << endl;
    cerr << "Testing next, reset, length, sum, and mean (62 points).\n";
    result = test1();
    value += result;
    if (result > 0) cerr << "Test 1 passed." << endl << endl;
    else cerr << "Test 1 failed." << endl << endl;

    cerr << "\nTEST 2:" << endl;
    cerr << "Testing minimum and maximum member functions (7 points).\n";
    result = test2();
    value += result;
    if (result > 0) cerr << "Test 2 passed." << endl << endl;
    else cerr << "Test 2 failed." << endl << endl;

    cerr << "\nTEST 3:" << endl;
    cerr << "Testing the + operator (7 points).\n";
    result = test3();
    value += result;
    if (result > 0) cerr << "Test 3 passed." << endl << endl;
    else cerr << "Test 3 failed." << endl << endl;

    cerr << "\nTEST 4:" << endl;
    cerr << "Testing the * operator (7 points).\n";
    result = test4();
    value += result;
    if (result > 0) cerr << "Test 4 passed." << endl << endl;
    else cerr << "Test 4 failed." << endl << endl;

    cerr << "\nTEST 5:" << endl;
    cerr << "Testing the == operator (7 points).\n";
    result = test5();
    value += result;
    if (result > 0) cerr << "Test 5 passed." << endl << endl;
    else cerr << "Test 5 failed." << endl << endl;

    cerr << "If you submit the statistician to Dora now, this part of the\n";
    cerr << "grade will be " << value << " points out of 90.\n";

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "i cannot seem to get them to work"? Are you having errors, the semantics are wrong, something else?

Comment: Sorry. i believe i have the syntax incorrect. lets just start with the  + operator. if i can figure this one out, the others may make more sense.  s1 + s2 should be a new statistician that behaves as if it had all of the  numbers of s1 followed by all of the numbers of s2.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check what warnings you've got?

for example:

```
statistician operator * (double scale, const statistician& s)
{
    double multiply;
    multiply = (s.total * scale);
    return s;
}
```

> warning: variable 'multiply' set but not used

and in the == operator:

```
bool operator ==(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
{
    return (s1 == s2);
}
```

You should tell it how to compare, but what you did is a recursion.

Comment: Sorry. i believe i have the syntax incorrect. lets just start with the + operator. if i can figure this one out, the others may make more sense. s1 + s2 should be a new statistician that behaves as if it had all of the numbers of s1 followed by all of the numbers of s2.

Comment: just create temporary statistician object, do the sum to the object member, and return the object.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, note that `operator+` and `operator*` have been made `friend`s of class `statistician`, as such, those operators have access to private members of instances of class `statistician`.

Now, you want to implement those two operators, this may look like this:

```
statistician operator + (const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
{
    statistician s3; // build up new instance
    s3.count = (s1.count + s2.count); // initialize it's fields based on operands
    return s3; // return new instance
}

statistician operator * (double scale, const statistician& s)
{
    statistician s3; // build up new instance
    s3.total = (s.total * scale); // initialize it's fields based on operands
    return s3; // return new instance
}
```

Going further, with your current implementation:

```
bool operator ==(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
{
    return (s1 == s2);
}
```

the call to `operator==` ends with an infinite recursion (very bad). To solve this, it should look something like that:

```
bool operator ==(const statistician& s1, const statistician& s2)
{
    return (s1.count == s2.count); // or whatever that makes two instances of statistician "equal"
}
```